# Mysql - Join matches and non-matches

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is related to my other question:
[Managing Foreign Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579249/managing-foreign-keys)

I am trying to join the table of matches and non-matches.

So I have a list of interests, a list of users, and a list of user interests.

I want the query to return all interests, whether the user has the interest or not (should be null in that case), only where the user = x. Every time I get the query working its only matching interests that the user specifically has, instead of all interests whether they have it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    interests i 
LEFT JOIN  userinterests ui ON i.interestID = ui.interestID 
LEFT JOIN  users u ON ui.userID = u.uiserID 
and u.userID = ?
```

If you put a where condition on a table that should have no records inteh main tbale, you convert the join from a left join to an inner join. The only time you should ever have a condition inthe where clasue for something one the right side of a left join is when you are searching for records that don't match (where u.userid is null, for instance)

Of course you should define the fields to be selected and never use select * in production code especially not when you have a join as it sends repeated information across the network (the data inteh join feilds is repeated) and is a waste of resources and poor prgramming practice for multiple reasons.

Comment: I think select * is just for the examples sake, I definitely wouldn't be using it. However, I'm not sure how this answers my question? I need both the rows that do and don't match, which is why I think I may only be able to do the union.

Comment: This should give you the rows that do and don't match. That is pupose of the left joins. It will give all records from INeterests and if there are users attached to those interests it wil display them as well.

Comment: Perfect! Sorry I guess I missed the AND instead of the WHERE, as the code looks the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should rather use `LEFT JOINS`

Something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    interests i LEFT JOIN
        userinterests ui ON i.interestID = ui.interestID LEFT JOIN
        users u ON ui.userID = u.uiserID
WHERE userID = ?
```

where is the user id you are looking for.

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` in MySQL stands for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: I can't get that working for some reason. I did find that this works.. but its probably not the best.

SELECT *
FROM interests
LEFT JOIN user_interests ui ON ui.interest_id = interests.interest_id
WHERE user_id = '1'
UNION
SELECT * FROM interests
LEFT JOIN user_interests ui ON ui.interest_id = interests.interest_id